# Find real $x$ satisfying $(x+3)^5 – (x-1)^5 \geq 244$

Tags: functions

Solve for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if

$(x+3)^5 – (x-1)^5 \geq 244$

The answer is given as $\left ( -\infty ,-2 \right ]\cup \left ( 0,\infty  \right ) $

Comment: Please give some context, and explain what you know about the problem and what you've tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle y = \frac{(x+3)+(x-1)}{2} = x+1\Rightarrow x= y-1$$

Put into $$\displaystyle (x+3)^5-(x-1)^5\geq 244$$

So $$(y+2)^5-(y-2)^5\geq 244$$

Now Using the formula

$$\displaystyle (2+y)^5 = \binom{5}{0}y^5+\binom{5}{1}y^4\cdot 2+\binom{5}{2}y^3\cdot 2^2+\binom{5}{3}y^2\cdot 2^3+\binom{5}{4}y\cdot 2^4+\binom{5}{5}\cdot 2^5$$

Similarly Put $y\rightarrow -y$

We get $$\displaystyle (2-y)^5 = -\binom{5}{0}y^5+\binom{5}{1}y^4\cdot 2-\binom{5}{2}y^3\cdot 2^2+\binom{5}{3}y^2\cdot 2^3-\binom{5}{4}y\cdot 2^4+\binom{5}{5}\cdot 2^5$$

So we get $$4\left[5y^4+40y^2+16\right]\geq 244\Rightarrow 5y^4+40y^2+16\geq 61$$

So we get $$5y^4+40y^2-45\geq 0\Rightarrow y^4+8y^2-9\geq 0$$

So we get $$y^4+9y^2-y^2-9\geq =0\Rightarrow (y^2+9)\cdot (y^2-1)\geq 0$$

So we get $$y^2-1\geq 0,$$ Bcz $$(y^2+9)>0\forall y\in \mathbb{R}$$

So $$y^2-1\geq 0\Rightarrow y\leq -1\cup y\geq 1\Rightarrow (x+1)\leq -1\cup (x+1)\geq 1$$

So we get Solution of the equation

$$(x+3)^5-(x-1)^5\geq 244$$ is $$x\in \left(-\infty,-2\right]\cup \left[0,\infty\right)$$